# how to remove consecutive digits from a df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I want to remove rows which contains consecutive digits in a df and at the end a 0 such as 12340 or 45670. I tried this code but nothing changed

```
rows_to_remove = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    digits = [int(d) for d in str(row['prix'])]
    if all([digits[j+1]-digits[j] == 1 for j in range(len(digits)-1)]) and digits[-1] == 0:
        rows_to_remove.append(i)

df = df.drop(rows_to_remove)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
consecutive = '123456789'

m = [not (s.endswith('0') and s.rstrip('0') in consecutive)
     for s in df['prix'].astype(str)]

out = df[m]
```

Output:

```
    prix
1  12378
2  12345
```

How this works:

```
consecutive = '123456789'

df['keep'] = [not(s.endswith('0') and s.rstrip('0') in consecutive)
              for s in df['prix'].astype(str)]

print(df)
```

Output:

```
     prix   keep
0  123450  False
1   12378   True
2   12345   True
3   45670  False
```

Reproducible input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'prix': [123450, 12378, 12345, 45670]})
```

##### 2 digits numbers

If you want to keep 2 digits numbers such as `20`:

```
consecutive = '123456789'

m1 = np.array([not(s.endswith('0') and s.rstrip('0') in consecutive)
               for s in df['prix'].astype(str)])
m2 = df['prix'].lt(100)

out = df[m1|m2]
```

Or:

```
m = [not (s.endswith('0') and len(s) > 2 and s.rstrip('0') in consecutive)
     for s in df['prix'].astype(str)]

out = df[m]
```

Output:

```
    prix
1  12378
2  12345
4     20
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'prix': [123450, 12378, 12345, 45670, 20]})
```

Comment: What happens if the number is 20, 30, ..., 90? Should be dropped it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you would like to filter out stringified ints which end in `'0'` (the int is a multiple of 10), AND when stripped of trailing 0's, is of length 2+ and is a substring of `'123456789'`?

If so, I believe this will work:

```
from pandas import DataFrame, Series

# Some test data
df = DataFrame({
    'i': [
        1,
        10,
        11,
        12,
        120, # Dropped
        122,
        123,
        1230, # Dropped
        12300, # Dropped
        1240,
        13,
        130,
        134,
        1340,
        2,
        20,
        21,
        210,
        2120,
        23,
        230, # Dropped
        2340, # Dropped
        234000, # Dropped
        2350,
        123456789,
        1234567890 # Dropped
    ]})

filt = Series(s.endswith('0') and len(s.rstrip('0')) > 1 and s.rstrip('0') in '123456789' for s in df['i'].astype(str))

filtered_df = df.loc[~filt]
```

You could split the logic up to make it more readable, and string filters together with the `&` operator:

```
stringified = df['i'].astype(str)

filt_1 = Series(s.endswith('0') for s in stringified)
filt_2 = Series(len(s.rstrip('0')) > 1 for s in stringified)
filt_3 = Series(s.rstrip('0') in '123456789' for s in stringified)

filtered_df = df.loc[~(filt_1 & filt_2 & filt_3)]
```

(There may also be ways to make the filtering more efficient)